# Can Chrome/Google Track Multiple Accounts After I use Ghostery, CCleaner, reboot router etc

Tags: google-chrome, privacy, google-accounts

I use two Google accounts, usually one for YouTube and another for Gmail (but sometimes usage may extend to other Google services too). I share the 'Gmail ID' only with people I know [might call it my 'official' ID in a sense] while the 'YouTube ID' is for more general, public use.

I use/switch between these accounts as follows:

1. Never 'Sign in to Chrome'
2. Use Ghostery extension to block all trackers, except those under the head of 'Essential'
3. Cookies - 'Keep local data until you quit your browser'
4. Exit Chrome and run CCleaner to remove everything under Chrome, except Internet History and Saved Passwords
5. Reboot Router
6. Using MVPS Hosts file on Windows 8.1

My name and date of birth is real in both accounts, but neither is the 'existing' account for the other. On a few occasions, I might have just logged out of one and logged in to other without doing CCleaner or Reboot.

Can Chrome still track I'm using two Accounts? I'm not doing anything illegal (besides maybe violating Google usage Agreement , I guess). Just curious to know and also some desire for not to be tracked, no special reason.

Comment: Google doesn't care you have multiple google accounts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Chrome (and google) can track that you are using two accounts from the same computer.

Since Chrome is an application on your computer, there is a great number of ways that you can be tracked including:

- some kind of cache
- registry
- any kind of fingerprinting mechanism

Just youtube (or any other Google website) has the possibility of tracking you in a great number of ways, including:

- Canvas fingerprinting
- WebGL fingerprinting
- Fonts fingerprinting
- Installed plugins
- User agent
- OS + resolution
- IP Address
- DNS Leak
- WebRTC Leak
- Any combination of the above
- many more

See Panopticlick (https://panopticlick.eff.org/) or Browserleaks (browserleaks.com) to get a glimpse of what can track you.

Now, even though they CAN, it does not mean that they DO.